# pass uri to webbrowser control on next page

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, uri, webbrowser-control

Hi i am new to Windows Phone development, i have an app to download rss feeds via webclient, they are set to a listbox via syndicationitem and now i want to open these feeds (the selected one) in a webbrowser control on an another page, a standalone page just for displaying the page that was clicked in the listbox, i mean the uri. the problem is the uri is set in this call on my mainpage.xaml.cs via

```
SyndicationItem sItem = (SyndicationItem)listBox.SelectedItem;

if (sItem.Links.Count > 0)
            {
                Uri uri = sItem.Links.FirstOrDefault().Uri;
                WebBrowserTask webBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask();
                webBrowserTask.Uri = uri;
                webBrowserTask.Show();
            }
```

I know want to set instead of this above WebBrowserTaks an WebBrowser control which would be on a seperate page like "preview.xaml" i can set the navigation like

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Preview.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

but how to pass the uri with this navigation to the WebBrowser control on this page?! i have no other code on this other page, its just a an empty page that has an Title and an WebBrowser control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing data between pages is accomplished with the use of the query string in your navigation call. For instance, you would modify your selection changed handler to do something like the following:

```
private void listBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var myUri = new Uri("/Preview.xaml?url=" + Uri.EscapeDataString((string)listBox.SelectedItem), UriKind.Relative);

    NavigationService.Navigate(myUri);
}
```

Note that the data that is being passed in the query string should contain escaped characters.

I've generated a simple example of the Preview page with only a web browser control:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <phone:WebBrowser x:Name="webBrowser" />
    </Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

And attached a load handler:

```
public partial class Preview : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public Preview()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Loaded += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("url") &&
                Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(NavigationContext.QueryString["url"], UriKind.Absolute))
            {
                webBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(NavigationContext.QueryString["url"], UriKind.Absolute));
            }
            else
            {
                // TODO: Handle url parameter exception
            }
        };
    }
}
```

As you can see in this approach, it may be worthwhile to validate that you have a meaningful URL parameter before attempting to navigate the browser control and handle any errors as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) do you can also help me to hide the navigation on my homepage before it loads to the webbrowser control, i have a mobile version of my website and there is just an <div> on top that i want to hide but have no clue how to do it just for the webbrowser control in the app, so the <div> remains still visible to other users like Desktop and other mobile users.